# Добавление объекта в массив объектов без повторений

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

я добавляю в массив объектов объект в двумя полями, как сделать чтоб добавлялись лишь уникальные объекты, у них всех id уникальный. Потому что при выборе одного и того же объекта он будет добавлен несколько раз.

```
const choiseOrg = (title, value) => {
        setoptionOrg('Выберите организацию')


        if (user.selecetedOrg === undefined) {
            setUser({ ...user, 'selecetedOrg': [{'value':value,'title': title}] })
        } else {
            
            const setelect = user.selecetedOrg;
            setUser({ ...user, 'selecetedOrg': [...setelect, {'value':value,'title': title}] })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю о чем речь, не вижу где тут id и у какого объекта они уникальны.

Попробуйте проверять на уникальночть через includes

```
if(!array.includes(user.id)) {
    ...добавить в обьект
}
```

includes проверяет, есть ли такое значение в array

--- **Дополнение**

Вот, надеюсь понятно будет:

```
let user = {
    selectedOrg: [
        {value:1,title:'text'},
        {value:2,title:'text'},
        {value:3,title:'text'}
    ]
}

const choseOrg = (title, value) => {
    if(!user.selectedOrg.find(i => i.value === value)) {
        user.selectedOrg.push({value: value, title: title})
        console.log('добавлено: ', {value:value, title: title})
    } else {
        console.log('пропущено: ', {value:value, title: title})
    }
    
}

choseOrg('text2',1) //-> пропущено, потому что такой value уже есть
choseOrg('text2',3) //-> пропущено, потому что такой value уже есть
choseOrg('text2',4) //-> добавлено
```

Comment: В value приходит id, забыл написать

Comment: я обновил ответ